# how to use eth_estimateGas for erc20 tokens?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, erc-20, gas-estimate

i wanna calculate estimate gas for BNB, PAX, LINK
i have used geth 1.8 and web3.php

my contract data that used (i found them from etherscan):

```php
<?php
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public static array $PAX = [
        'abi' => '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"assetProtectionRole","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"betaDelegateWhitelister","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"proposedOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"EIP712_DOMAIN_HASH","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"supplyController","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"currentOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"proposedOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferProposed","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"oldProposedOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferDisregarded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"addr","type":"address"}],"name":"AddressFrozen","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"addr","type":"address"}],"name":"AddressUnfrozen","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"addr","type":"address"}],"name":"FrozenAddressWiped","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"oldAssetProtectionRole","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"newAssetProtectionRole","type":"address"}],"name":"AssetProtectionRoleSet","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"SupplyIncreased","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"SupplyDecreased","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"oldSupplyController","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"newSupplyController","type":"address"}],"name":"SupplyControllerSet","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"seq","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"fee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BetaDelegatedTransfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"oldWhitelister","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"newWhitelister","type":"address"}],"name":"BetaDelegateWhitelisterSet","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"newDelegate","type":"address"}],"name":"BetaDelegateWhitelisted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"oldDelegate","type":"address"}],"name":"BetaDelegateUnwhitelisted","type":"event"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"initialize","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"initializeDomainSeparator","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposedOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"proposeOwner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"disregardProposeOwner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"claimOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"reclaimPAX","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newAssetProtectionRole","type":"address"}],"name":"setAssetProtectionRole","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"freeze","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"unfreeze","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"wipeFrozenAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"isFrozen","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newSupplyController","type":"address"}],"name":"setSupplyController","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseSupply","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseSupply","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"target","type":"address"}],"name":"nextSeqOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"sig","type":"bytes"},{"name":"to","type":"address"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"fee","type":"uint256"},{"name":"seq","type":"uint256"},{"name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"betaDelegatedTransfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"r","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"v","type":"uint8[]"},{"name":"to","type":"address[]"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256[]"},{"name":"fee","type":"uint256[]"},{"name":"seq","type":"uint256[]"},{"name":"deadline","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"betaDelegatedTransferBatch","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"isWhitelistedBetaDelegate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newWhitelister","type":"address"}],"name":"setBetaDelegateWhitelister","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"whitelistBetaDelegate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"unwhitelistBetaDelegate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]',
        'address' => '0x8e870d67f660d95d5be530380d0ec0bd388289e1',
        'div' => '1000000000000000000',
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public static array $BNB = [
        'abi' => '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdrawEther","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"unfreeze","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"freezeOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"freeze","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"name":"decimalUnits","type":"uint8"},{"name":"tokenSymbol","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Freeze","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Unfreeze","type":"event"}]',
        'address' => '0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52',
        'div' => '1000000000000000000',
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public static array $LINK = [
        'abi' => '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"transferAndCall","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]',
        'address' => '0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA',
        'div' => '1000000000000000000',
    ];
```

but i always get this errors, and errors are different between all of them:

**BNB:**

my payload:

```json
{"id":41949930,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"from":"0xa96Ce4C161271C797d979017821A278e1481eAfA","to":"0xb8c77482e45f1f44de1745f52c74426c631bdd52","data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000008eac6bfe4cf663b4a4a0ffbcd93277dbcbc11c5500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8"}]}
```

result:

```
{#76
  +"jsonrpc": "2.0"
  +"id": 41949930
  +"error": {#79
    +"code": -32000
    +"message": "execution reverted"
  }
}
```

**PAX:**

my payload:

```json
{"id":1544773853,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"from":"0xa96Ce4C161271C797d979017821A278e1481eAfA","to":"0x8e870d67f660d95d5be530380d0ec0bd388289e1","data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000008eac6bfe4cf663b4a4a0ffbcd93277dbcbc11c5500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8"}]}
```

result:

```
{#76
  +"jsonrpc": "2.0"
  +"id": 1544773853
  +"error": {#79
    +"code": 3
    +"message": "execution reverted: insufficient funds"
    +"data": "0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012696e73756666696369656e742066756e64730000000000000000000000000000"
  }
}
```

**LINK:**

my payload:

```json
{"id":579853267,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"from":"0xa96Ce4C161271C797d979017821A278e1481eAfA","to":"0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca","data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000008eac6bfe4cf663b4a4a0ffbcd93277dbcbc11c5500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8"}]}
```

result:

```
{#76
  +"jsonrpc": "2.0"
  +"id": 579853267
  +"error": {#79
    +"code": -32000
    +"message": "invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe not defined"
  }
}
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimation wont work if the `from` account doesn't have the tokens, since the call would fail. You need to put the tokens you're `estimateGas`ing for into the `from` address, or use a wallet that already has the tokens as the `from` address